# Why a / img is not working with the selector?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('.navbuttons a');
  var container = $('.contentcontainer');

  trigger.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.data('target');
    container.load(target);
    console.log("success");
    return false;
  });
});
```

To work with this:

```html
<br>
<h1 id="contentheader">
  <br><br><br> 
  Course List
</h1>
<ul class="course1">
  <li id="course1img">
    <a href="#" data-target="webdev.html">
      <img src="image/webdev.jpg" width="550" height="450" data-target="webdev.html">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-target="webdev.html" class="listlink">
      <h2>
        Diploma
        <br> in
        <br> Web Development
      </h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="course2">
  <li id="course1img">
    <a href="#" data-target="cpuscience.html">
      <img src="image/cpuscience.jpg" width="550" height="450">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-target="cpuscience.html" class="listlink">
      <h2>
        Diploma
        <br> in
        <br> Computer Science
      </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried changing `var trigger = $('');` value to a / img but it's not working.

Comment: can you explain what you want to do? Your question is vague at the moment

Comment: Neither `.navbuttons` nor `.contentcontainer` exist in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry. Am i suppose to add in the main html page? I'm doing a simple website with navigation buttons. Now I manage to load my html pages using jquery with the menu buttons. After loading 1 page, I have this page with 2 Images with each image details as link. I was hoping to click this image and text link that loads in another page. .navbuttons are my main button's className. .contentcontainer is where I'm trying to load in the html file i showed here

Comment: Change `var trigger = $('.navbuttons a');`  to ` var trigger = $('ul li a');`  and you are good to go

Comment: Ya i tried it already as it is not working. When i clicked on the img / text link, It brings me back to same page.

Comment: But the classes you are using do not exist

Comment: This works: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/4f197e9b326d5fcec649087579a72562 (no jQuery)

Comment: You want that the new elements on the container.load has assigned the event.
In the way you are printing DOM elements that aren't when you assign the 'click' event, they dont have the behaviour.  
Everytime you have new elements you must add the event to them.

Comment: I have the main html file but i am not able to edit. for the script.js it was meant to be for my main html and i was thinking to use the function again on this html file i posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more clear with the question. As said on comments your code are not working and the class navbuttons neither contentcontainer aren't declared.

In despite of this I think I know where is your problem.

As you are reprinting items on the html you must assign another time the bindings to the DOM elements.

Think on your code as:

```
//The initial load bindings
function load_bindings(){
 var trigger = $('.navbuttons a');
 var container = $('.contentcontainer');

 trigger.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.data('target');
  container.load(target);
  //to add bindings inside the elements on container
  reload_bindings();
  console.log("success");
  return false;
 });
}

//The function to add new bindings elements
function reload_bindings(){
 var container = $('.contentcontainer');
 var trigger = $('.navbuttons a',container);
 //only add to the 'a' elements inside the container
 trigger.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.data('target');
  container.load(target);
  reload_bindings();
  console.log("success");
  return false;
 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 load_bindings();
}
```

Is not the best code, I hope you understood the problem and rethink to get a better code. It could be done with less lines.